# Navigation Menu animation with add/removeClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, navbar

I am new to JS/jQuery and it is my first time to animate a navigation bar.
 After learning the addClass/removeClass functions, i got the next challenge. 
 I do not get it to fadeIn/fadeOut the addClass/removeClass elements. 
Maybe someone could help me :-)

```
    $(window).scroll(function(){                          
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 80) {
            $('.navbar').removeClass('.navbar').addClass("navbar-alt").fadeIn(500);
            $('.logo-ate').removeClass('.logo-ate').addClass("logo-ate-alt");
            $('.links').removeClass('.links').addClass("links-alt");
            $('.menu').removeClass('.menu').addClass("menu-alt");
        } else {
            $('.navbar').removeClass("navbar-alt").addClass('.navbar').fadeOut(500);
            $('.logo-ate').removeClass("logo-ate-alt").addClass('.logo-ate');
            $('.links').removeClass("links-alt").addClass('.links');
            $('.menu').removeClass("menu-alt").addClass('.menu');
        }
    });
});
```

I used removeClass/addClass because i wanted to change colours/images in the menu on scroll.
The Navigation Menu i am working on should look like theirs : https://www.piccola-koeln.de/ 
I got everything working except the fadeIn/fadeOut.

Comment: Is `navbar` hidden that you want to use `fadeIn`?

Comment: I guess that is the problem, the navbar is not hidden since it should change colors and images with a fade.

Comment: The fadeIn() is used when an element is hidden and you want to show it using a fade effect. In this case no show/hide effect is needed. I guess only changing classes are enough. Please present details of classes to check what they do.

Comment: Is there a way to fadeIn a background color? That would solve my problem aswell. From 0 opacity to 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I have to say that scroll event is a fast repeating event when a user uses mouse wheel or touch slide so you should not add and remove classes frequently with no meaning by every scroll event! So I have added a criteria in addition to scroll position which tests if `navbar` or `navbar-alt` class was set before.

For color fade effect there is no need to add a separate block. You can use css transitions so when the class is changed, the styles appear by css effects:

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){                          
        if ( $(this).scrollTop() > 80 &&  $('.navbar').hasClass("navbar") ) {
            $('.navbar').removeClass('.navbar').addClass("navbar-alt");
            $('.logo-ate').removeClass('.logo-ate').addClass("logo-ate-alt");
            $('.links').removeClass('.links').addClass("links-alt");
            $('.menu').removeClass('.menu').addClass("menu-alt");
        }

        if ( $(this).scrollTop() <= 80 &&  $('.navbar').hasClass("navbar-alt") ){
            $('.navbar').removeClass("navbar-alt").addClass('.navbar');
            $('.logo-ate').removeClass("logo-ate-alt").addClass('.logo-ate');
            $('.links').removeClass("links-alt").addClass('.links');
            $('.menu').removeClass("menu-alt").addClass('.menu');
        }
    });
```

```css
.navbar {
  height:80px;
  background-color:#666666;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;left:0;
  width:100%;
  transition: background-color 1s ease;
}

.navbar-alt{
  height:80px;
  background-color:#00ff00;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;left:0;
  width:100%;
  transition: background-color 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navbar">&nbsp;</div>
scroll down<br>
.<br>
.<br>
.<br>
.<br>
.<br>
.<br>
scroll down<br>
.<br>
.<br>
.<br>
.<br>
.<br>
.<br>
scroll down<br>
.<br>
.<br>
.<br>
.<br>
.<br>
.<br>
scroll down<br>
.<br>
.<br>
.<br>
.<br>
.<br>
.<br>
scroll down<br>
.<br>
.<br>
.<br>
.<br>
.<br>
.<br>
scroll down<br>
.<br>
.<br>
.<br>
.<br>
.<br>
.<br>
Now scroll up!<br>
.<br>
.<br>
.<br>
.<br>
.<br>
.<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried a bit more and found a solution :

```
.colorfade {
  height:100px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  z-index: -1;
}


    $(window).scroll(function(){                          
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 80) {
            $('.navbar').removeClass('.navbar').addClass("navbar-alt");
            $('.logo-ate').removeClass('.logo-ate').addClass("logo-ate-alt");
            $('.links').removeClass('.links').addClass("links-alt");
            $('.menu').removeClass('.menu').addClass("menu-alt");
            $('.colorfade').fadeIn(500);
        } else {
            $('.navbar').removeClass("navbar-alt").addClass('.navbar').fadeIn(500);
            $('.logo-ate').removeClass("logo-ate-alt").addClass('.logo-ate');
            $('.links').removeClass("links-alt").addClass('.links');
            $('.menu').removeClass("menu-alt").addClass('.menu');
            $('.colorfade').fadeOut(500);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: instead of adding a new element for color fade, you can use css transition for `navbar` itself.

Comment: I would need the transition on scroll, could you give me an example how it should work since i never used css transition?